# cjs extension for chrome: how to add multiple scripts?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do you add multiple external scripts using cjs extension for chrome  ?

It only agrees to load the first line then it tries to load //localhost/script2.js//localhost/script3.js//localhost/script4.js
(=it merges line 2 to 4 in one url)

whatever I try to use for new line (copy/pasting from a text editor or direct edition)

Chromium 54/windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a semicolon after each line.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js;
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.7.1/d3.min.js;
```

Comment: It looks like you're right. You shouldn't trust the advice given by the app itself which is "# Uncomment address of script below or type your own (ONE PER LINE)"

Comment: Yup. Had to figure this out myself this morning. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you but I already switched to tampermonkey. Too bad the author takes time to write documentaiton just to write it badly.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely looks like a bug to me so I gave up cjs and replaced it with tampermonkey extension which works as expected

// @require      https://localhost/js/jquery.js 
// @require      https://localhost/js/jquery-ui.js